# NULL values while exporting data from remote MySQL server into TSVs

Tags: mysql, null, csv

I need to export a large number of tables (~50) as TSVs from a remote MySQL server (so SELECT INTO OUTFILE is not an option per documentation).  I am using mysql -e 'SELECT * FROM table' > file.tsv (in a script that loops for each of the ~50 tables).  The problem is that with this way, NULL values in all the table are represented as 'NULL' string instead of \N.  The 'NULL' then gets converted/casted to odd/undesirable values when the TSVs are loaded back into a local DB (using LOAD DATA INFILE).  For example, a date column with NULL is read as '00-00-0000', a varchar(3) column is read as 'NUL'.

I've confirmed that when using SELECT INTO OUTFILE NULLs are correctly represented as \N in the TSV and therefore loaded back into DB correctly.  I've also confirmed that if I change the 'NULL' in the TSV to \N the data is loaded corrected.

My question is how do I export the data from the remote server such that the TSVs retain \N in the first place.  Are the better ways then doing a SELECT * and redirecting the output to a file?  Appreciate any tips! as this NULL issue is bothersome.

Comment: Can't you use the ``IFNULL`` function to set the value to ``\N``? ex ``SELECT IFNULL(myfield, '\N') FROM MYTABLE``. I haven't fully understood the question because I am not aware of TSV files so maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @MponosGeorge - thanks for reading and thanks for the suggestion!  I am exporting 50 some tables, all with multiple fields that could be NULL so I can't specify the field name unless I do 50 some queries.  I am looking for some config option that will represent NULLs as \N.  I considered setting things like 'FIELDS ESCAPED BY' option but it doesn't seem possible with SELECT *

Comment: it's just crazy that mysql cannot import data it's own tool exported. I'm here 8 years later still dealing with the same problem.